# Access ODBC Issue: ODBC--Call failed

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, ms-office

I created an Access front end for a SQL DB on my PC for use throughout my company.  I am using a file ODBC connection and putting both the ODBC file and the Access file on a shared network drive.

When I load the access file, for some reason it seems to default to using my windows login credentials and pulls in the data perfectly.  When a user attempts to open the file, they receive an error message saying "ODBC --call failed.".  I can open the Linked Table Manager for them and check 'ask for new location' then specify the ODBC file and it all works fine...however it doesn't seem to save anything.  I get the error each time someone other then myself opens this file.

Any idea what could be wrong?  I am not an Access guy by trade, it just seems to be the tool we need for the moment.

--EDIT: For Clarification I am using a file ODBC connection

--Edit 2--

Riddle me this.  So I have been troubleshooting this issue and I came across something interesting.  I was logged in as one of my users and did the following:

1. Create a new access file that references a file ODBC connection on the desktop.
2. Create 3-4 linked tables in the access file, using the ODBC file on the desktop.
3. Save and close the access file.
4. Re-Open said file.... and I get an ODBC connection error!  Right after everything was fine in a fresh file!

Anyone ever experience this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to narrow the issue a bit.  Access for some reason keeps trying to use Windows Credentials instead of the username in my ODBC file.  I can't find a way around it, but I was able to resolve the issue by creating logins on my SQL Server for the windows users that need access.

I am not incredibly happy about needing to manage more logins, but that's what i did to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

i assume you didn't install the ODBC correctly on each users PC.
you should create the ODBC-definition. You can create the relevant statements directly in the registry, see this branch
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI
if you give the same name as on your developer machine, then it works. that's how i do it with my client applications that i develop on my machine and then install it at client site

Comment: I thought that since the ODBC file was on a shared drive that would be enough.  So I will need to install an ODBC file on each machine separately?

Comment: aha, you use a FILE for the ODBC connection - do the users have rights to access the share, and is it mapped with the same drive letter/path ? (would have to test it once, but today i'm off the whole day ...)

Comment: They all have access to the drive yes.  I believe it is mapped to the same drive letter but it is possible that it isn't.  How would I go about fixing that if they are different drive letters?

Comment: I just double checked.  At least one of the machines does have the same drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to resurrect the dead, but I had this same error stem from a different issue.

I was using an ODBC connection. When running the file using the 'Design' run button it worked fine. When I tried using the Navigation Pane and double clicking on it, the error would happen.

The structure of my query was the problem; I was porting a SQL server query over and the single quote ' parameter passing was not well received in Access. Changing these over to double quotes " made it work.

Answer (score 1):

After beating my head against the wall having this same issue, I finally discovered I had a checkbox on the Access form that defaulted to NULL.  Since I put the backend into SQL, the checkbox fields cannot be NULL but the 'ODBC Call Failed' message did not help.  I finally tried to add a record directly on the table via Access and it gave more information.  I set all the checkboxes to default to zero and it resolved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were columns having +' or -' substring combinations; error disapeared after removing ' characters from column definition